# qsort comparison function not working

Tags: c, string, sorting, pointers

I need to sort an array of strings, taken as input.
Help me with the pointers here please.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
    char* s1 = (char*)a, s2 = (char*)b;
    int len1 = strlen(s1), len2 = strlen(s2);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i< len1 && i<len2; i++){
        if(s1[i] > s2[i])   return 1;
        if(s1[i] < s2[i])   return 0;
    }
    return 0;   
}

int main() {
    int i;
        int len;
        scanf("%d",&len);
        char* a[len];
        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            a[i] = (char*)malloc(13);
            scanf("%s",a[i]);
        }
        qsort(&a, len, sizeof(char*), compare);
        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            printf("%s\n",a[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with the compare function only.

Comment: `if(s1[i] < s2[i])   return 0;`  should be `if(s1[i] < s2[i])   return -1;`. Also note that `aaa` will compare equal to `aaax` with the current compare method.

Comment: The bulk of the `compare()` function should just be a call to `strcmp()`. Aso, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169) in C.

Comment: `qsort()`'s comparator should return to it `<0` if the left/right elements sort ascending, `0` if they are equal, and `>0` if they sort descending. I don't think you can get away with only returning `1` or `0`. I mention this because your question comes up quite high in related search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* s1 = (char*)a, s2 = (char*)b;
```

declares `s1` as a pointer and `s2` as a char, because `*` binds to the variable on the right, not to the type on the left. You need to write:

```
char *s1 = *((char**)a), *s2 = *((char**)b);
```

The compiler should have given you a bunch of warnings and errors about `s2` because of this. When I tried to compile your code, I got:

```
testsort.c: In function 'compare':
testsort.c:6: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
testsort.c:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast
testsort.c:10: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
testsort.c:11: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
```

With these correction, the program compiles cleanly and runs correctly:

```
$ ./testsort
5
abc
12345
foo
aaa
bbb
```

Output:

```
12345
aaa
abc
bbb
foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Your data array is an array of char * , so the comparison method gets passed 'pointers to pointers' (char**) by qsort.

You need:

```
char *s1 = *((char**)a), *s2 = *((char**)b);
```

Comment: What you're saying is graspable but `char *s1 = (char*)a, *s2 = (char*)b` works just fine.

Comment: +1, this is of course correct. No point in dropping `const` from the arguments, though.